# When to use empty event accessors in c#?

Tags: c#, events, accessor

Interface-Events can be Implemented explicit. For example we are able to [pass 
delegates to another Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ak9w5846.aspx).

Here the `TestHandler`-Event is wrapped *(not sure if its the right term)* by the `SomeHandler`-Event to Implement the `ISomeHandleable`-Interface.

```
public delegate void HandlerDelegate();

public interface ISomeHandleable
{
    event HandlerDelegate SomeHandler;
}

public class Test : ISomeHandleable
{
    event HandlerDelegate ISomeHandleable.SomeHandler
    {
        add { TestHandler += value; }
        remove { TestHandler -= value; }
    }

    public event HandlerDelegate TestHandler;


    public void Fire() => TestHandler?.Invoke();
}
```

I have just recently seen, that we are also able to Implement `ISomeHandleable.SomeHandler`as follows:

```
event HandlerDelegate ISomeHandleable.SomeHandler
{
    add { }
    remove { }
}
```

But I have not yet found any documentation and possible usecases to this, and I also dont understand what it does.

I only know, delegates can still be added to `ISomeHandleable.SomeHandler` but the Event cannot be invoked by the Class `Test` anymore.

But as you can define Events with empty Accessors, **what does it do and how is it meant to be used?**

Comment: http://blog.slaks.net/2013-12-01/creating-unused-events/

Comment: Ahh cool. this pretty much answers the question. Thx.